# Why does this Python function not release memory after execution?

Tags: python, memory, beautifulsoup

I have a Python script that looks through an XML file that has been passed through Beautiful Soup looking for a text term. I then traverse to the value I want to extract and return the string. This works but as I have added calls to this function in the program main loop I eventually get MemoryError problems. Looking in Windows Task Manager I have found that the memory is not released after each call and the system runs out of memory. The problem appears to be the 'return myLink.string' line. Is this holding a reference to an object in memory and how can I get round this?

```
def FindUptime(soup):
    link = soup.find(text=re.compile("Uptime"))
    if link:
        myLink = link.parent
        myLink = myLink.next_sibling
        if myLink.string == "Up:":
            myLink = myLink.next_sibling
            myLink = myLink.next_element
        else:
            print "Can't find Up: term"
        return myLink.string
    else:
        print "Can't find Uptime"
        return ""
```

Called by

```
readings[sensorIds[i][SENSOR_NAME]] = FindUptime(soup)
```

Comment: what do you do with the returned link in the program main loop?

Comment: Hi, the return result is assigned to a dictionary of results. (The script pulls together uptimes from servers into a dictionary which is later written to a Powerpoint report)

Comment: Hi, the return result is assigned to a dictionary of results. (The script pulls together uptimes from servers into a dictionary which is later written to a Powerpoint report)

Comment: readings[sensorIds[i][SENSOR_NAME]] = FindUptime(soup)

Comment: Can you do the following: return a constant or a new string like "100" instead of `myLink.string` and see what happens?

If the memory problem still remains, then probably the `soup` has a leak somewhere in its methods. Also, I'd try having `re.compile()` only once and using the result in all subsequent `find()`s (just for testing)

Comment: Hi, I returned a constant as advised and the issue goes away. Looking at the memory profile in Task Manager I see the memory released every iteration. Interestingly, when I changed the parser for BeautifulSoup back to the standard one (I was using 'lxml') the problem disappears. Looks like a leak in lxml. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try using soup but before returning `myLink.string` copy the string value into new, clean string of Python native type and return that copied string. I have a vague suspicion that the myLink.string could have some hidden reference in it.

Comment: Andrei - Thanks a lot! It is now working as I wanted. I thought I had already tried this using an intermediate variable but I think I didn't create a string initially. Tried again and converted using the str() method and it releases properly. Ideally I would like to understand why but for now it will get my report done. (Newbie to Python but ex-C programmer still having challenges to think in a Pythonic not C way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified to...

```
def FindUptime(soup):
    link = soup.find(text=re.compile("Uptime"))
    if link:
        myLink = link.parent
        myLink = myLink.next_sibling
        if myLink.string == "Up:":
            myLink = myLink.next_sibling
            myLink = myLink.next_element
        else:
            print "Can't find Up: term"
        uptime = str(myLink.string) # added
        return uptime
    else:
        print "Can't find Uptime"
    return ""
```